# Can't assign related/up-sell/cross-sells with configurable product

Tags: magento

I set up configurable products but when I go to related products or cross/up-sells I have an empty list and can't assign them. Does anybody have a clue why this is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have reset the filter ? if not just reset the filter and try assigning product.

Comment: As commented by Manoj and Amasty it looks like you have some filter aplied that is resulting in no products being displayed.You need to reset filter and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please press "reset filter" button to see all products as at the image:

[image: reset-filters]

Comment: Thanks guys! First magento project so still need to learn these features. But it works as a charm!